# Countdown with individual Sound

Tags: java, android, timer, media-player, countdown

I have a problem with my countdown and I want to play an individual sound at the end. For this I have created a list. When the corresponding picture is clicked, the selection should be saved and played in this method:

```
private void loadMusic() {
if (timerStatus == TimerStatus.PAUSED)
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            playSound(R.raw.sound1);
        }
        public void playSound(int sound1) {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), (R.raw.sound2));
            mp.start();
        }
    }.run()
}
```

I tried to solve this with an array in the onCreate method, but this is "void" and therefore I don't get a return:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.sound);

    final int[] selection = new int[1];
    imageButton1 = findViewById(id.iv_bowl1);
    imageButton1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        selection[0] = 1;
        Toast.makeText(Sound.this, "1-click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
    return selection[0];
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific of what's your problem/what's not working?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i have now changed the above.